# addClass is not a function when using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a JS function to render a "button" in my web pages UI.
The button is build using a CSS-formatted DIV, which contains an icon image, and some text. I have found some issues where the text overflows the button (due to user browser font settings) and I want to add a scroll bar if this happens.

But, when trying to add the class to add make the text div scrollable, I get *"addClass is not a function"*.

Here's my function.  Followed by example of it being called.

```js
function renderButton(btnArea,btnClass,btnOnclick,btnIcon,btnText,btnId) {
    var btndiv = $("<div>").addClass(btnClass).attr("onclick",btnOnclick).attr("id",btnId);
    var btnimg = $("<img>").addClass("btnicon").attr("src",btnIcon).attr("id",btnId+"img");
    var btntxt = $("<div>").addClass("btntext").text(btnText).attr("id",btnId+"txt");
    btndiv.append(btnimg);
    btndiv.append(btntxt);
    $(btnArea).append(btndiv);
    txtIdSelector = "#"+btnId+"txt";
    if ($(txtIdSelector)[0].scrollHeight > $(txtIdSelector)[0].offsetHeight ) {
        $(txtIdSelector)[0].addClass("scrollable");
    }
}

button_icon = file_path+"death_icon_white.svg";
button_text = "Death England & Wales GRO Index entry (1993 onwards) abcd def ghi jkl mno";
button_id = "btn"+"001";
renderButton("#btn-test-area","choicebtn","sayHello()",button_icon,button_text,button_id);
```

I could previously get this working using HTML DOM as follows, but I believe I should be using jQuery to be more efficient.

```js
offset_height = document.getElementById("btn001txt").offsetHeight;
scroll_height = document.getElementById("btn001txt").scrollHeight;
if (scroll_height > offset_height) {
  document.getElementById("btn001txt").classList.add("scrollable");
}
```

Any clues why my jQuery function isn't working?
Thanks

Comment: `$(txtIdSelector)[0].addClass()`  - you're using `.addClass` on a plain DOM element, not a jQuery element.

Comment: Or in other words, `document.getElementById` is pure JavaScript. Write `jQuery('#btn001txt').addClass('scrollable');`.

Comment: Okay, I changed         $(txtIdSelector)[0].addClass("scrollable"); to         $(txtIdSelector).addClass("scrollable");  - This works

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments:

❌ Receiving an HTML element like this is pure JavaScript and does not return a jQuery object:

```js
  document.getElementById("btn001txt")
```

✅ Instead select the element with `jQuery('#btn001txt')` so that `addClass` is available on the jQuery object:

```js
  jQuery('#btn001txt').addClass('scrollable');
```

---

As stated in your own comment, `$(txtIdSelector).addClass("scrollable");` fixed the behavior.